# Can't use android:background with button from the new material components

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I'm using the new material components `com.google.android.material:material` with android x but I can't set a custom background to the button.

I know that I can use `app:backgroundTint` to change the color

but the default background has some padding that I want to get rid of, and the old way of using `android:background` to set my own background but this is no longer working.

I looked at the [docs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) but can't find any mention to this change.

Comment: You can use ImageButton instead of Button from material components. android:background is working on ImageButton.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The documentation for the `MaterialButton` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) says:

> Do not use the `android:background` attribute. `MaterialButton` manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background means `MaterialButton` can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will function properly. If the default background is changed, `MaterialButton` cannot guarantee well-defined behavior.

However, [the GitHub readme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) says:

> Note: `MaterialButton` is visually different from `Button` and `AppCompatButton`. One of the main differences is that `AppCompatButton` has a `4dp` inset on the left and right sides, whereas `MaterialButton` does not.

This mentions only left/right inset, but [the Attributes section](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#attributes) of the readme shows that all four insets are supported:

[image]

So you could add these attributes to your `<MaterialButton>` tag:

```
android:insetTop="0dp"
android:insetBottom="0dp"
```

Comment: no, I need to worry about it, as it still showing at the button and the top.

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:insetTop="0dp"` (and `insetBottom`) on your `<MaterialButton>` tag?

Comment: so how we can add gradient in materialButton?

Comment: not working for me, the buttons are still having a dark black background

Comment: This is not a solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751122/2914140 or solutions below.

Answer (score 26):

In the Material Components Library, the `MaterialButton` has a default style with `insetBottom` and `insetTop` with a value of `6dp`.

You can change it using:

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:insetTop="0dp"
      android:insetBottom="0dp"
      ../>
```

[image]

If you want to change the **background color** you can use the `app:backgroundTint` attribute or you can override some theme attributes from a default style then you can use new **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute.

In your case you can do something like:

```
<style name="MtButtonStyle"
 parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
   <item name=“materialThemeOverlay”>@style/GreenButtonThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="GreenButtonThemeOverlay">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Finally starting with the version **`1.2.0-alpha06`** you can use the **`android:background`** attribute in the `MaterialButton`.

```
<MaterialButton
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
    ... />
```

Comment: Please note that version 1.1.0 in alpha status *for now* https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material

Comment: @eugeneek Yes it is still in alpha, it will be in beta this week.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, I often see you use alpha and beta versions of support libraries. How do you know when they obtain a new functionality? Do you work at Google? :)

Answer (score 10):

Looking at https://medium.com/@velmm/material-button-in-android-e4391a243b17 I found that `app:backgroundTint` (and `app:backgroundTintMode`) works. It changes a color, but not a drawable selector.

[Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743190/when-using-theme-materialcomponents-light-noactionbar-style-setting-button-back) you can replace `<Button` with `<android.widget.Button`.

Comment: you safe my life. thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use gradient drawable as `MaterialButton`'s background,

set Your `MaterialButton` as below:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="16dp"
     app:backgroundTint="@null"
     android:background="@drawable/group_47"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/input_password"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/input_password"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_password" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work, did you add something else to make it work? Just setting background and tint to null doesn't  work

Comment: @ZeusAlmighty please  tell me your reqirements, and how you tried

Comment: I tried it by setting `background=@drawable/custom_bg` and `backgroundTint="@null"`. I want to use the color of background drawable as background of Material button but it is using primary color as background.

Comment: @ZeusAlmighty can u share ur material button and style.xml file

Comment: How do I send it?

Answer (score 9):

If you wish to keep your

```
android:background="@drawable/button_background"
```

And have **MaterialButton** respect it, then you must set

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
app:backgroundTintMode="add" // it doesn't matter the value, but it must be set
```

Please note that you can also use **app:background** instead, although I've noticed enough breaking changes that I still prefer the method above.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue when I use state drawable in a Button but It does not change the background of the button. After searching for a long time, I found 2 solutions as below:
The first solution is change the application theme from **MaterialComponents** to **AppCompat** in values/themes.xml file. then state drawable will work well.

to

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

If you still want to use **MaterialComponents** theme then you can try the second solution.
Use <**android.widget.Button** instead of <**Button** or <**com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton**

```
    <android.widget.Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/state_test"
        android:text="Button" />
```

The second solution I found at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743190/when-using-theme-materialcomponents-light-noactionbar-style-setting-button-back/52751122#52751122)

Answer (score 2):

using a simple

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

with button attributes works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for this decision by the google design team to exclude the functionality `android:background="@drawable/"` from the initial release versions of the material library is to enable developers to build consistent and professional-looking designs for apps at a faster pace. This is because most developers like me are bad in making decisions related to design and colors of the app.

Also, I found this snippet from [google tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64OD1PAqELg) while migrating to MDC.

[image: replace with this code]

Answer (score 0):

Just by using android:backgroundTint

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/pink</item>
</style>


<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/followButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/channel_header_item_margin"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titeChannelTV"
    style="@style/MyButtonStyle"/>
```