# When using Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar style, setting Button Background has no effect

Tags: android, styles, themes

In order to use Chip and ChipGroup, I set Application style extends  `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` int manifests.xml, then I set Button "android:background" attr, but it does not effect! why? and what can I do?

This is my style:

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/header_color</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    <!--<item name="buttonStyle">@style/AntButton</item>-->
    <!--<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/AntButton</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:button"></item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:progressTint">@color/ffc000</item>-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ffc000</item>
</style>


<style name="AntButton" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">88dip</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <!--<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>-->
</style>
```

I have tried to change buttonStyle and materialButtonStyle, but not effect too!

this is my layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:divider="@drawable/shape_divider_05dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle">

        <!--only can use backgroundTint to change background color-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/item_popupwindows_Photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:text="Pictrue"
            android:textColor="@color/c_666666"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <!--background not effect !!-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/item_popupwindows_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/c_666666"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is result :

[image]

Because I have used Chip and ChipGroup in APP, I have to user theme extends MaterialComponents! do you know how to resolve it ？please tell me, thanks!

in this page [Can't use android:background with button from the new material components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673053/cant-use-androidbackground-with-button-from-the-new-material-components), the author wants to change the default padding, but I want to change the `backgroundDrawable`, so, it does not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use android:background with button from the new material components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673053/cant-use-androidbackground-with-button-from-the-new-material-components)

Comment: The important thing to understand is that using that theme changes the `LayoutInflater` that's used to inflate your layouts. This special layout inflater replaces generic `<Button>` tags with `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>` tags, and so you get different behavior from the framework's Button.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you want a true `Button`, but one that you can modify like the framework `Button` (instead of the `MaterialButton`), then you can explicitly specify the framework version in your layout file. Replace this:

> ```
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/item_popupwindows_cancel"
>     ... />
> ```

with this:

```
<android.widget.Button
    android:id="@+id/item_popupwindows_cancel"
    ... />
```

This will give you what it says on the tin: an `android.widget.Button`, which should respond to styling the way you expect.

Similarly, you could use a `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>` if you want support library features but not material components features.

Comment: thanks very much , It worked for me . But i din't know why can not user <Button></Button>  ?

Comment: When you use a non-namespaced tag, like `<Button>`, the LayoutInflater will choose which concrete implementation to inflate. Since you have a `Theme.MaterialComponents` theme, the LayoutInflater will choose to inflate material components versions of widgets when possible. In other words, with that theme, `<Button>` and `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>` are identical. But you can choose a different implementation by specifying it, like `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>` or `<android.widget.Button>`.

Comment: @BenP., yes. Not only `LinearLayout`, but other containers too (ConstraintLayout, FrameLayout, etc).

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, the `LinearLayout` holding your second `Button` seems to have a white background color. That means you don't need to explicitly specify a white background for your `Button`; you can just let the `LinearLayout`'s background show through.

This can be accomplished by using [the "Text Button" style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#text-button) of `MaterialButton`:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
```

Comment: Thanks,  i want to change the button background drawable, not only change the background color .

When i use TextButton style , also can't change background drawable, it's only change the default background color to transparent.

And now i had to use  TextView  instead of Button, it's a temp solve. If you have some other msg , please tell me , Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for change the color

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ImageButton instead of Button from material components. android:background is working on ImageButton.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/item_popupwindows_cancel"
    ... />
```